# Azure - Python Dash Application

Tags: python, azure

I have a Dash application and I have got some questions for the Azure (App Services) deployment. I use git in Deployment Center.

**1)** In my requirements.txt I have a packages that is causing the issue - pywin32. It gives me the below error during the deployment:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32==302 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32==302

It happens during the installation of dependencies.

**2)** When I remove pywin32==302 from requirements.txt, I can build and deploy however the applications shows me the error (I did before Flask deployment and it worked).

Any ideas how to fix it please?

```
Logs here:
2021-12-14T14:09:25.051923007Z Updated PYTHONPATH to ':/tmp/8d9bee966ce1769/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages'
2021-12-14T14:09:25.497472285Z [2021-12-14 14:09:25 +0000] [37] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2021-12-14T14:09:25.500486120Z [2021-12-14 14:09:25 +0000] [37] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (37)
2021-12-14T14:09:25.504178862Z [2021-12-14 14:09:25 +0000] [37] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2021-12-14T14:09:25.507938905Z [2021-12-14 14:09:25 +0000] [39] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 39
2021-12-14T14:09:26.617892557Z Application object must be callable.
2021-12-14T14:09:26.619256872Z [2021-12-14 14:09:26 +0000] [39] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 39)
2021-12-14T14:09:26.677663238Z [2021-12-14 14:09:26 +0000] [37] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-12-14T14:09:26.677730439Z [2021-12-14 14:09:26 +0000] [37] [INFO] Reason: App failed to load.
/home/LogFiles/2021_12_14_pl0sdlwk00000V_docker.log  (https://*****.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/2021_12_14_pl0sdlwk00000V_docker.log)
2021-12-14T14:04:22.384Z INFO  - Stopping site ***** because it failed during startup.
2021-12-14T14:09:08.430Z INFO  - Starting container for site
2021-12-14T14:09:08.430Z INFO  - docker run -d -p 1972:8000 --name taxdevelopment_0_bbeb99e2 -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=***** -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=*****.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=31a267ed7b71ec86982412cc9dc4ad2f31ca2b8f51b692363aa765c405b03b84 appsvc/python:3.8_20210810.1
2021-12-14T14:09:08.431Z INFO  - Logging is not enabled for this container.Please use https://aka.ms/linux-diagnostics to enable logging to see container logs here.
2021-12-14T14:09:10.641Z INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container *****_0_bbeb99e2 for site *****
2021-12-14T14:09:33.292Z ERROR - Container *****_0_bbeb99e2 for site ***** has exited, failing site start
2021-12-14T14:09:33.294Z ERROR - Container *****_0_bbeb99e2 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8000, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2021-12-14T14:09:33.300Z INFO  - Stopping site ***** because it failed during startup.
/home/LogFiles/webssh/.log  (https://*****.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/webssh/.log)
```

Comment: Your local laptop runs windows desktop presumably? I don't think you will find many desktop functionalities in Azure. pywin32 allows you to use the windows API's but flask is a backend server software, which I think conflicts in what you want. Where do you use pywin32 for? Also, show the complete error stack for a better guess on what breaks.

Answer (score 0):

> ERROR - Container *****_0_bbeb99e2 for site ***** has exited, failing site start
>
> ERROR - Container *****_0_bbeb99e2 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8000, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.

The error message shows that failing to start site on linux container. It might be using some additional references of your Dash application. You can use Container logs to view the detailed information of error.

1. Docker logs appear on the Container Settings page in the portal.
2. You can find the Docker log in the /LogFiles directory. You can access this via the Kudu (Advanced Tools) Bash console or by using
   an FTP client to access it.
3. You can use our API to download the current logs.

Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/29678/diagnose-container-start-issues-in-azure-app-servi.html)

Any way you already removed the `pywin32 == 302` from **requirements.txt** and you can check the same `pypiwin32==302` in **requirements.txt** and remove it.

Refer [here](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/error-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-pywin32-301-from-versions-none/15343) for more information